# PHP redirect using get when login is done

Tags: php, url, authentication, get

```
    $redirect=$_GET["r"];
if ( isset($_GET["r"]) ){
    header("location: http://" .$redirect);
} else {
    $redirect = "mickiewiki.nl/login/profile.php";
    header("location: http://" .$redirect);
```

this code won't work? I want it to be like if I go to mickiewiki.nl/login/login.php?r=mickiewiki.nl/Doneer.php that when I login I go back to the page Doneer.php

When I login, I am always being sent to profile.php no matter if I add my r or not

```
 <?php
   //allow sessions to be passed so we can see if the user is logged in
   session_start();

   //connect to the database so we can check, edit, or insert data to our users table

   $database = mysql_select_db('***', $con) or die(mysql_error());

   //include out functions file giving us access to the protect() function made earlier
   include "login/functions.php";
   $selectedid = $_GET['id'];
   if(empty($selectedid)) {
        $selectedid = $_SESSION['uid'];
   }
   if(strcmp($_SESSION['uid'],"") == 0){
        header("location: login/login.php?r=mickiewiki.nl/Doneer.php");
   } else {
   ?>
```

Comment: What does 'it doesn't work' mean? What is it actually giving you?

Comment: I am still being sent to http://mickiewiki.nl/login/profile.php even though my r isn't empty

Comment: Show us how you're using your initial fetching method. That GET is coming from somewhere. Or is that what you were saying about `mickiewiki.nl/login/login.php?r=mickiewiki.nl/Doneer.php` ?

Comment: yes I go to that site, I want it to be redirected to the page that stands after the r=

Comment: Do you have any code after this (you don't exit the script after the redirect)? And `var_dump($_GET)` seems the place to start.

Comment: In order for this to work, your HTML link needs to be `<a href="mickiewiki.nl/login/login.php?r=mickiewiki.nl/Doneer.php">LINK</a>` with the full domain and not just `login.php?r=mickiewiki.nl/Doneer.php` I tested your code using my own domain, and it worked. @MickRustenhoven

Comment: if(strcmp($_SESSION['***'],"") == 0){
 header("location: http://mickiewiki.nl/login/login.php?r=mickiewiki.nl/Doneer.php");

not working..

Comment: Ah, using sessions and login features I see, that's a whole different ball of wax. @MickRustenhoven - Why don't you just show us your full code and the way you're actually using it? Minus the actual DB credentials. I for one, can't help you any further unless I see full code. If someone else can figure it out, good.

Comment: fred, could you help me via teamviewer?

Comment: Try using `<input type="hidden" name="r" value="<?php echo $_GET['r'];?>">` inside your form. @MickRustenhoven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form on your website, you are not setting `r` through `GET`.  You have `username`, `password` & `submit` for your form - and nothing for `GET`.  If you are submitting `r` with your form (which I cannot see that you are), then you should probably be checking for `$_POST['r']` instead of `$_GET['r']`.

Basically, you need to add a hidden field for your `r` variable and submit that along with your form.

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
<input type="hidden" name="r" value="<?php print $_GET['r']; ?>">

<p><label for="name">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" /></p>
<p><label for="pwd">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
<p>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Slight typo in `value="<?php print $_GET['r']; >"` which should be `value="<?php print $_GET['r']; ?>"` missing `?`

Comment: Don't forget to fix the missing `?` @MickRustenhoven Unless you noticed that already. This guy didn't fix the error yet and will produce an error if left like that.

Comment: Yea I already noticed and fixed, I use Dreamweaver so it showed me :) but thanks guys, really needed this!

Comment: Thanks, fellows.  I added in the missing `?` to the example code.

Answer (score 0):

but, you must do a control for $_GET["r"] ... and why it doesn't work?

Comment: go to the site, try to login with username test, password test, by going to http://mickiewiki.nl/Doneer.php you'll understand what I mean